# Help with understanding non-isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is a question from my course, which I am having problems understanding.

> For each integer $n>1$, give examples of non-isomorphic groups of order $n^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $n>1$, the groups $\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are both of order $n^2$ and are non-isomorphic, since the first is cyclic and the second one is not.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: Not often I type quick enough (at my age) to beat anyone to it!